# why I am getting this error {message: "no such table: books (code 1)?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, react-native

I have a React native component which the purpose is to register a new book into sqlite database , my problem is that it pops up an error saying that

> {message: "no such table: books (code 1)

I am sure that there is a table called books , and I have a function checking if there is a database in my project and it shows that there is a DB , here is my code of how I am checking the DB :

```
 componentDidMount() {
    db = SQLite.openDatabase({ name: "read.db", location: "default" },
        this.openSuccess, this.openError);
}

openSuccess() {
  alert("Database is opened");
}

openError(err) {
  alert("error: no database");
}
```

the path of my data base file  is :

> android/app/src/main/assets

and here is my query :

```
const title = 'myBook';


        try{
          db.transaction((tx) => {
            let sql = `INSERT INTO books (book) VALUES ("${title}")`;
            try{
            tx.executeSql(sql, [], (tx, results) => {
                alert('Register successfuly!');
            });
          }catch(e){
              alert('not working');
          }

      });
    }catch(e){
      alert('error');
    }
```

could you please help

Comment: Does the error message say `books` or `placements`?

Comment: books not placements error while I was typing , thanks any suggestions to solve it ?